# Python - How to return to previous function after calling another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, game-development

Heres the copy of my code :) this game is part of my personal activity.
so after purchasing a clue **(from: def game_hints)** i want to return to **def Game_process.**

```
import random     
    SCORE = 0
    ROUNDS = 1
          
    def player_stats():
        print(f"SCORE: {SCORE} | ROUNDS: {ROUNDS}")
    
    def game_hints():
        print("Would you like purchase a hint for 5 points? [1/2]: ")
        USER_HINT = int(input())
        global SCORE

        if USER_HINT == 1:
           points -= 5
        if Mystery_NUM % 2 == 0:
           divisibility = "even"
        else:
           divisibility = "odd"    
        if player_guess > Mystery_NUM:
           value = "smaller"
        else:
           value = "larger"  
        
        print(f"CLUE: Mystery Number is {divisibility} and try a {value} guess | -5 POINTS")

 
      
    def Game_Process():
     global ROUNDS
    
     while True:
      if ROUNDS <= 10:   
        Mystery_NUM = random.randrange(10)
        print(Mystery_NUM) #remove before final product 
        print("Guess the num [1-10]: ")
        USER_GUESS = int(input())
        if USER_GUESS == Mystery_NUM:
            print("\nGood Job! +5 Coins!")
            global SCORE
            SCORE = SCORE + 10
            ROUNDS += 1
            player_stats()    
        else:
            print("Wrong! Try Again")
            game_hints(USER_GUESS, Mystery_NUM)
      else:
        print("Game Over!")
        Game()        
    
    def Game():
        user_opt = input("\"Welcome to Guess Game\" \nPress [Y] to Play or [N] to Exit: ").lower()
        if user_opt == "n":
            print("Good bye!")
            exit()
        elif user_opt == "y":
            Game_Process()
        else:
            print("Invalid Input! [1/2]")
            Game()
    Game()
```

As shown below, this is the fuction for the hints. I was able to call this function but the only problem is that the after this fuction is done, it changes the Myster_Num.

```
    def game_hints():
        print("Would you like purchase a hint for 5 points? [1/2]: ")
        USER_HINT = int(input())
        global SCORE

        if USER_HINT == 1:
           points -= 5
        if Mystery_NUM % 2 == 0:
           divisibility = "even"
        else:
           divisibility = "odd"    
        if player_guess > Mystery_NUM:
           value = "smaller"
        else:
           value = "larger"  
        
        print(f"CLUE: Mystery Number is {divisibility} and try a {value} guess | -5 POINTS")
```

Comment: Maybe you want `if/elif/elif/elif/else` in `game_hints()` instead of `if/if/if/if/else`?

Comment: Aside: indenting one space makes the code hard to read. PEP recommends 4 spaces. Have a look at [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Just remove the `else` part in your `game_hints()`, the call will go back to `GameProcess()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must remove the else statement in the **game_hints** function because it restarts a full **GameProcess** and therefore indeed recompute a mysterious number.

Then, when you exit **game_hints** and come back to **GameProcess**, you must not come back to the big loop because it will indeed recompute a mysterious number. The solution is to have an inner loop inside each round that you exit only if the player guessed the correct value using the **break** keyword.

```
def Game_Process():
    SCORE = 0
    ROUNDS = 1
    while True:
        if ROUNDS <= 10:
            Mystery_NUM = random.randrange(10)
            print(Mystery_NUM)  # remove before final product
            while True:
                print("Guess the num [1-10]: ")
                USER_GUESS = int(input())
                if USER_GUESS == Mystery_NUM:
                    print("\nGood Job! +5 Coins!")
                    SCORE = SCORE + 10
                    ROUNDS += 1
                    player_stats()
                    break
                else:
                    print("Wrong! Try Again")
                    game_hints(USER_GUESS, Mystery_NUM)
        else:
            print("Game Over!")
            Game()
```

Comment: thank you, it solved my problem :)